# how can i clear that secret Veneer

Tags: everyday-chemistry

[image]

Hi
my friend gave me a mysterious 10 dollars and on the back of it there's a secret code hidden but theres something weird on it covering it what i don't know how to erase it. This is the picture i feel like its thicker than an actual dollar this is all i know.
Could anyone help me solve the problem ? How and with what can i erase it?

Comment: Please tell us some more information about what is covering it. Is it hard? Is it brittle? Is it smooth?

Comment: Can you read the code through the bill by shining a bright light through it?  Maybe its not meant to be removed.  You can, however, run a bill through the washing machine.

Answer (score 3):

Use household tools!

- Can you bend or fold the note? Is the layer brittle and does break off?
- Can you scratch the layer off with a sharp blade?
- Place the note between paper (kitchen roll) and use a hot flat iron. Does the layer melt?
- Can you wash the layer off using a cotton bud and

  - water
  - methylated spirit
  - nail polish remover

Comment: tanX for help its soft paper and

Comment: tanX for help its soft paper and i try this solutions but dos't work

Answer (score 0):

Try dissolving it in ethanol or some kind of alcohol. Alcohol is polar so it would dissolve the cover if the substance is polar. The dollar bill is non polar and wouldn't be dissolved.

Comment: special tnx but alcohol acid and nail polish remover dosnt work on it